# Iterate through every PAIR OF COLUMNS inside an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that contains serial numbers(sn) of spare parts and production dates (pd) among many other extra data.

So far in order to find some extra data that refer to a specific sn I used the search function in excel. However a sn can have several pd and thus i had sometimes to click on the search button for more than a hundred times....

pd is always in a column on the left of the column where sn is. But there are more than 200 columns and their position isnt fixed...i.e. sometimes pd is in column 22 and sn in column 23 but sometimes pd is in column 66 and sn in column 67. Always in neighboring cells with pd on the left.

```
So far I have the following code:

Sub FindBoard()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastCell As Range, NextCell As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim sthlh As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
      '  Find LastRow. Works Best. 1st and last cells can be empty
         If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
         'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Rows.
              LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
         'Search for any entry, by searching backwards by Columns.
              LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
           'MsgBox "Last Cell" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Cells(LastRow, LastColumn).Address
           MsgBox "The Last Row is: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & LastRow
           MsgBox "The Last Column is: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & LastColumn
         End If
       ' Number of columns based on actual size of log range NOT MyAr(n)
       Set NextCell = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(LastRow + 1, (LastColumn - 10))
    End With


   For r = 1 To LastRow
            'For sthlh = 2 To LastColumn**
                If Cells(r, "AP") = "0600263" Then
                    If Cells(r, "AO") = "4112" Then
                    Exit For
                    End If

                End If
            'Next sthlh**
    Next r

    If r > LastRow Then
        MsgBox " not found"

    Else
        ' found in row
        MsgBox "The board u r looking for is in row: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & r
        Rows(r).Select

End If
End Sub
```

I try to add the two lines with the double asterix ** in order not to use spcific columns like I do in my code but to have sth like this:

.....

```
   For r = 1 To LastRow
            For sthlh = 2 To LastColumn
                If Cells(r, sthlh ) = "0600263" Then
                    If Cells(r, sthlh-1) = "4112" Then
                    Exit For
                    End If

                End If
            Next sthlh
    Next r
```

.....

where 4112 is pd 
and 0600263 is sn

My aim is to iterate through Iterate through every PAIR OF COLUMNS of the excel sheet and when i find the sn to check if the pd is the desired one. If yes to select the row so that i can see the extra data i want.

Any idea where I m doing it wrong???
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do these numbers always look the same? so pd are always 4 integers and sn are always 7 integers? For last row and last column there are better ways: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Comment: yes always the same! thnks for the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindBoard()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim sthlh As Long
Dim found As Boolean
Dim Paire As Range

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

found = False

r = 0
Do Until r > LastRow Or found = True
r = r + 1
            For sthlh = 2 To LastColumn
                If Cells(r, sthlh) = "0600263" Then
                    If Cells(r, sthlh - 1) = "4112" Then
                    found = True
                    Set Paire = Range(Cells(r, sthlh - 1), Cells(r, sthlh))
                    Exit For
                    End If

                End If
            Next sthlh

Loop

    If found = False Then
        MsgBox " not found"

    Else
        ' found in row
        MsgBox "The board u r looking for is in row: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Paire.Address
       Paire.Select

End If
End Sub
```